# Saving prstat on solaris to file using python script

Tags: python, solaris

I have a python script I want to run it on a solaris box to get me what prstat returns.

I have the following code:

```
import os, subprocess

with open("test.txt", "w") as outfile:
  subprocess.call("prstat -cZ 1 2", shell=True, stdout=outfile)
```

it returns this error:

```
File "top.py", line 3
    with open("test.txt", "w") as outfile:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when I run `prstat -cZ 1 2 > testfile.txt` I get the output to a file named testfile.txt

Comment: Which version of python do you have?

Comment: Python 2. I realized that it works on python 3 but I can't change the python 2 on the boxes as they are on production, is there another way of getting the stats in python 2?

Comment: which version of python 2? 2.4?